# Are the 2nd order linear differential equations vector space?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Consider a homogeneous 2nd order linear diﬀerential equation
$$a(x)y''(x) + b(x)y'(x) + c(x)y(x)=0,$$
where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are given functions of $x$.

Let $V$ be the set of all real solutions $y(x)$ of this equation.  Prove that $V$ is a vector space and show that it’s 2-dimensional and isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: What are the definitions of a vector space? Does solutions to your differential equation statisfy these? How about dimension? What does it _mean_ that a vector space is $2$-dimensional? These are the questions you should ask yourself when you see this problem. Some would even go so far as to say you should _always_ ask yourself similar questions whenever you're asked to show _anything_ in mathematics.

Comment: Thank you...Yes that is a real help and i appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**
Certainly the set $\Omega$ of all real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space and $V \subseteq \Omega$. So we only need to prove $V$ is a subspace, i.e. that $0 \in V$ and $V$ is closed under addition and constant multiplication. That $0 \in V$ is straight-forward (can you prove it)? Now assume $x,y \in V$ and let $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Can you prove $kx \in V$ and $x+y \in V$?

That $V$ is 2-dimensional will require showing that its basis has 2 elements, i.e. that only 2 things in $V$ can be chosen linearly independent. How do you test for functions to be linearly independent?

Isomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is easy. Once you prove it's 2-dimensional, pick $x,y \in V$ as its basis and consider the function $f:V \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which maps any $z = c_1 x + c_2 y \in V$ to $(c_1,c_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for any $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$...

Comment: @Arash: I think you need to know [Superposition principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle).

Comment: @B.S. agree, forgot to mention, thank you

Comment: @B.S.I need to know how to use mathjax first! I downloaded it into my HDD but i don't know how to use it!